# Garbage value received in client server communication c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I was trying to write a simple client server program on windows. My Server side code looks like below .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    SOCKET serverSock, clientSock;
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr, clientAddr;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WSAData);
    serverSock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port=htons(5555);

    bind(serverSock,(SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    listen(serverSock,0);
    std::cout<<"Listening for incoming connections \n";

    char buffer[1024];
    //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    int clientAddrsize= sizeof(clientAddr);
    if(clientSock = ( accept(serverSock,(SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrsize ) != INVALID_SOCKET) )
    {
        std::cout<<"Client connected \n";
        recv(clientSock,buffer,int(strlen(buffer)),0);
        std::cout<<"Client Says: " << buffer <<"\n" ;
        Sleep(10000);
        //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        closesocket(clientSock);
        closesocket(serverSock);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client side code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    SOCKET clientSock;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&WSAData);
    clientSock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(5555);

    connect(clientSock,(SOCKADDR *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    std::cout <<"Connected to the server \n";
    //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    char buffer[1024]={'h','e','l','l','o','.','\0'};
    send(clientSock,buffer,int(strlen(buffer)),0);
    std::cout<<"Message sent \n" ;
    Sleep(10000);
    closesocket(clientSock);
    WSACleanup();
    std::cout<<"Socket closed \n";
    return 0;
}
```

I see below output on server side:

```
 Listening for incoming connections
 Client connected
 Client Says: R☺
```

What i was expecting was `Client Says: Hello.` . Not sure why i am getting the garbage value.

Thanks

Comment: "Garbage" values almost always depends on either using uninitialized data (local variables or array elements); Or not adding, skipping over, or not counting the string null terminator.

Comment: By the way, `char buffer[1024]={'h','e','l','l','o','.','\0'};` is *exactly* the same as `char buffer[1024]="hello.";`

Comment: You need to always capture the value returned by recv() and act on it appropriately.  If you don’t, you can’t know how many bytes recv() actually wrote into your local buffer.  (It may be fewer bytes than you requested)

Comment: Case in point: `send(clientSock,buffer,int(strlen(buffer)),0);` will *not* send the null-terminator of `buffer`. And `recv(clientSock,buffer,int(strlen(buffer)),0);` uses the *uninitialized* (and therefore indeterminate, or garbage if you wish) contents of `buffer` to calculate the size of the array. So you have a combination of both the problems I listed before.

Comment: Also, passing strlen(buffer) in as the last argument to recv() doesn’t make much sense, since strlen() reads the bytes pointed to by its argument to see how long the string is, and at the time you call recv(), the string has not been received yet so that isn’t possible.  You probably want to pass sizeof(buffer) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buffer[1024];
```

This declares a local `char` array in automatic scope. The array is not initialized anything, and contains random garbage.

```
recv(clientSock,buffer,int(strlen(buffer)),0);
```

This passes `buffer` to `strlen`. However, `buffer` contains garbage, this is undefined behavior, with the eventual results could be, randomly, anything between an immediate crash, at this point, or some bizarre return value from `strlen`.

Additionally, the return value of `recv` ***is completely ignored and not checked at all***.

All socket system calls can fail, and every socket system call, `send`, `recv`, and all others can fail. Additionally, even if it succeeds, `recv` gives you ***no guarantees whatsoever*** that everything that was `send` in one shot, will be `recv`ed, in one shot.

If, for example, `send` sent 10 bytes, the first call to `recv` might return 1 or 5, indicating that only the first one or five bytes were immediately `recv`ed. You are ***not guaranteed*** that `recv` will receive those 10 bytes all at once. Otherwise, `recv` will (obviously) need to be called again to receive the rest of the message.

You will need to fix all of these issues in order to have a reliable client/server application:

1. Check the return value of all system calls. Everything that I said about `recv` also applies to `send` as well. An attempt to `send` 10 bytes might come back with, say, 7, indicating that only the first 7 bytes were sent, and you must then implement the appropriate logic to send the remaining bytes, too.
2. Fix undefined behavior, of passing an uninitialized value to `strlen`.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for detailed info. Appreciate it a lot. Can you point me to some practical implementation on this where i can see code for reference on how to handle a data serialized say by a brotobuf and sent can be read. Or any meaningful data  exchange example so that i can take a leaf out of it  or point to me a tutorial. Most on internet do not show how to handle and read tcp packets in recv call appropriately.